# What is the song playing in episode 100 of Black Clover?

Tags: music, black-clover

There is a song playing at around 20 minutes into the episode where Yuno uses mana zone to attack Licht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song you are looking for is "Haruka Mirai (ハルカミライ)" by "Kankaku Piero". It's the 1st OP.